# Elastic Search: parse_exception: failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new in `Elastic Search` and using ES in my application. When I run simple query on single table on ES then it working file.. But When I'm using nested query then it is not giving me proper result.

Basically, I have two tables `people` and `interactions` both are separate tables. And interaction table has person_id which refer to people table id. and I want to fetch those interaction of people which have `user_id: 2`. When I'm creating condition and running the query then I'm getting error.

Below is my query which I'm running.

```
{
  "index": "my_index",
  "type": "people",
  "fields": "_source,_timestamp",
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": {
          "wildcard": {
            "_all": "*a*"
          }
        }
      },
      "nested": {
        "path": "interactions",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": {
              "match": {
                "interactions.user_id": 2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      {
        "last_name": {
          "order": "asc"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the response which I'm getting

```
{
  "status": false,
  "error_code": 657,
  "errors": [
    "parse_exception: failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"
  ]
}
```

Below is the data which we index in ES

**People**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Test1",
        "last_name": "Data1",
        "date_of_birth": "1988-11-02",
        "created_at": ".......",
        "updated_at": ".......",
        "status": 1,
        "prefix": "Ms.",
        "suffix": "MD"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Test2",
        "last_name": "Data2",
        "date_of_birth": "1988-11-02",
        "created_at": ".......",
        "updated_at": ".......",
        "status": 1,
        "prefix": "Ms.",
        "suffix": "MD"
    }
]
```

**Interactions**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 11,
        "person_id": 6,
        "interaction_type": 1,
        "initiated_by": 2,
        "created_at": ".......",
        "updated_at": "......."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 10,
        "person_id": 5,
        ..........
    }
]
```

Can anyone suggest me what I'm doing wrong in this query?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show the mapping for your index  and a sample document

Comment: @blackmamba I updated my question with index mapping sample. Please suggest me how I can solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer.
Try this.

```
{
    "fields" : "_source,_timestamp",
    "size" : 10,
    "from" : 0,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [{
                    "wildcard" : {
                        "_all" : "*a*"
                    }
                }, {
                    "nested" : {
                        "path" : "interactions",
                        "query" : {
                            "bool" : {
                                "should" : {
                                    "match" : {
                                        "interactions.user_id" : 2
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort" : [{
            "last_name" : {
                "order" : "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Your json was malformed. You were missing a ']' for the Sort. Try the below

You can use a site like http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the jsons.

```
{
    "index": "my_index",
    "type": "people",
    "fields": "_source,_timestamp",
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0,
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "_all": "*a*"
                    }
                }
            },
            "nested": {
                "path": "interactions",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": {
                            "match": {
                                "interactions.user_id": 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "sort": [{
            "last_name": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```